# Reference- What does this line mean in ecmascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

Can someone help me to understand what this block is trying to say. I am going through understanding ecmaspec of `Object.is`. I come to this block of code. I am not able to understand what it is trying to depict is

```
2. If Type(x) is Number or BigInt, then
Return ! Type(x)::sameValue(x, y).
```

Full code is this:

```
1.If Type(x) is different from Type(y), return false.
2.If Type(x) is Number or BigInt, then
      Return ! Type(x)::sameValue(x, y).
3.Return ! SameValueNonNumeric(x, y).
```

I pretty much understand first and third statement but was not able to understand second point. Any help or reference would be helpful.

Here is doc reference:  https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-samevalue

Comment: Depending on the type it either calls [`Number::sameValue(x, y)`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-numeric-types-number-sameValue) or [`BigInt::sameValue(x, y)`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-numeric-types-bigint-sameValue)

Comment: @Andreas thanks alot. Have another question. What does !(<- this symbol mean). i.e what it depicts ! Type(x)::sameValue(x, y) in here

Comment: It's all in the linked document -> [5 Notational Conventions](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-notational-conventions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `x` is a number, use a `sameValue` overload method of one of the number types to compare `x` and `y`.

Comment: Thanks @Gosha. Have another question: what does it mean Type(x)::sameValue(x, y) i.e ::(these double colon means)

Comment: This means to call the `sameValue` method of what `Type(x)` returns.